# Updating a google chart with ajax on a timer using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I have a chart I want to append values to using a json response from an ajax call. I have created an API which returns a random number between 1 and 20, and i want to insert the response as the next value in the google chart.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night', 'width':400, 'height':300};
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            function: 'entityTrack',
            data: {
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occurred connecting to server. Please check your network');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if (json.status) {
                data.addRows([
                    ['Mushrooms', json.data.entityTrack]
                ]);
            }else{
                alert(json.message);
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    setTimeout(drawChart, 5000);
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

My chart renders with the text "No data". In my console log, every 5 seconds I am receiving the console.log(data) output which shows the current value my API delivered. Also, it does not append the data, it overwrites it.

When I put my declare statement for data outside the function, I run into DataTable is not defined console errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I was not calling the function after data was populated, so I rearranged my code and now its working.

I did the following changes: I made the updateChart function which exists inside the callback function from google.load, and I kept data outside of that function, so its rows are preserved. See:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night', 'width':400, 'height':300};
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    function updateChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                function: 'entityTrack',
                data: {
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('An error occurred connecting to server. Please check your network');
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if (json.status) {
                    data.addRows([
                        ['Mushrooms', json.data.entityTrack]
                    ]);
                    console.log(data);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }else{
                    alert(json.message);
                }
            }
        });
    setTimeout(updateChart, 5000);
    }
    updateChart();
}
```